# How to block certain cells in sheetJS Excel using protect

Tags: excel, sheetjs

How can we lock certain cells in excel by using SheetJs ws['!protect']

There is a Worksheet Protection Details section which has some keys but there usage is not clear from the documentation.

https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/blob/master/README.md

If somebody has used it or have any idea please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Yes, the documentation did not mention much except the keys [https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/csf/sheet][1]

From the code in their [github][2] and after testing it as well:
`ws['!protect']` requires an object.

The schema of the object is as follows(in typescript):

```
  {
    password?: string,
    selectLockedCells?: boolean,
    selectUnlockedCells?: boolean,
    formatCells?: boolean,
    formatColumns?: boolean,
    formatRows?: boolean,
    insertColumns?: boolean,
    insertRows?: boolean,
    insertHyperlinks?: boolean,
    deleteColumns?: boolean,
    deleteRows?: boolean,
    sort?: boolean,
    autoFilter?: boolean,
    pivotTables?: boolean,
    objects?: boolean,
    scenarios?: boolean,
   }
```

All keys are optional
[1]: https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/csf/sheet
[2]: https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/blob/5b4806bff01a9f4289b4c04e8a60a6c4c52fe93a/xlsx.js#L15292